# Rust crate including a large source file to initialize a Trie structure cannot compile (OOM)

Tags: rust

I have a `Trie` structure implemented in `Rust` which I took from somebody else and seems to work just fine:

```rust
pub struct Trie<K, V>
where
    K: std::fmt::Debug + Eq + Hash + Clone,
    V: std::fmt::Debug + Clone,
{
    value: Option<V>,
    children: HashMap<K, Trie<K, V>>,
}

impl<K, V> Trie<K, V>
where
    K: std::fmt::Debug + Eq + Hash + Clone,
    V: std::fmt::Debug + Clone,
{
    pub fn new() -> Trie<K, V> {
        Trie {
            value: None,
            children: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, path: Vec<K>, v: V) {
        if path.is_empty() {
            match self.value {
                Some(_) => panic!("key exists"),
                None => {
                    self.value = Some(v);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        self.children
            .entry(path[0].clone())
            .or_insert(Trie::new())
            .insert(path[1..].to_vec(), v)
    }

    pub fn fetch_or_default(&self, path: Vec<K>, default: V) -> V {
        let value = self.value.clone().unwrap_or(default);
        match path.len() {
            0 => value,
            _ => match self.children.get(&path[0]) {
                Some(child) => child.fetch_or_default(path[1..].to_vec(), value),
                None => value,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I have a special file where I initialize an instance of a Trie based on a dictionary containing 150k words, to which I each assign a number between 0 and 150.

The data was generated via JavaScript so it's not like it's impossibly huge, yet for some reason the Rust compile cannot handle it, and crashes out of memory despite my computer having 16Gb of memory + 2Gb swap (that it entirely uses before crashing).

```rust
use crate::data::*;

/*
a.reduce((str,ai,i) => { return str + ai.map((w,i) => `    //${w}\n    words_trie.insert(vec![' ',${w.split('').reverse().map(c => `'${c==`'`?`\\`:''}${c}'`).join(',')}], ${i});`).join('\n') + '\n' }, '');
*/

pub fn into(words_trie: &mut Trie<char, usize>) {
    // SPECIAL LINE, DO NO REPLACE BY ABOVE FORMULA
    words_trie.insert(vec![], 150);
    // ================================================
    //'n
    words_trie.insert(vec![' ', 'n', '\''], 0);
    ...
    //(150 000 times a comment followed by an insertion line)
    ...
}
```

The error message I get is the following one, but that's just the OOM killer at work:

```
process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name postag_nl_v1 src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=f33cf4c96979227f -C extra-filename=-f33cf4c96979227f --out-dir /home/fremy/Documents/postag_nl_v1/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/fremy/Documents/postag_nl_v1/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/fremy/Documents/postag_nl_v1/target/debug/deps` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
```

How can I get my Trie initialized based on the dictionary without making the compiler crash?

> **[EDIT] Here is a minimal repro, with dummy data:**
>
> https://gist.github.com/FremyCompany/1f6132441338f8b219d961c7254bd8ac#file-main-rs
>
> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhVrPgyThAkTgQ8v2U99Ffzug7rJ [1Mb zip]

Comment: I should mention that I use rust version `cargo 1.34.0 (6789d8a0a 2019-04-01)`

Comment: Does it work with 1.35.0 (latest stable)?

Comment: Because your examples does not have a `main`, I cannot reproduce your problem. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @hellow Just tried, this reproduces as well in `cargo 1.35.0 (6f3e9c367 2019-04-04)`. Technically, you can rename the `into` function into `main` and init the Trie, that would have the same result, but let me try to make a standalone. I can't set the data itself, so I need to process things a bit.

Comment: Do you have a single function consisting of 150,000 statements each creating a temporary `vec![]`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes.

Comment: Do you compile in Debug or Release?

Comment: @MatthieuM. doesn't seem to matter. I'm going to attach a minimum repro, just trying to build it now to make sure the issue is still there with the dummy data.

Comment: @MattieuM. Repro link added.

Comment: @FremyCompany please use [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible and **not** a url shortener and **not** onedrive to share sourcecode. Use https://gist.github.com or as said the playground.

Comment: @hellow Ok, I made a gist. It's a big gist though, it loads slowly. https://gist.github.com/FremyCompany/1f6132441338f8b219d961c7254bd8ac#file-main-rs